# Как при повторном нажатий поменять свойства блока?

Tags: jquery

Вот код:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#rslide").click(function(){
        $("#rslide").animate({right:'198'}, 300);
        $(".rslide").animate({right:'0'}, 300);
     });
  });
```

Но при повторном нажатий надо чтобы свойства поменялись

Comment: испопьзуй `toggle` https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rslide").click(function() {
    if (!($(this).hasClass("right"))) {
      $(this).addClass("right");
      $(this).animate({
        right: '198px'
      }, 300);
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("right");
      $(this).animate({
        right: '0'
      }, 300);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#rslide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rslide">Click me</div>
```

Comment: много почти повторного кода. введите `var rvalue = $(this).hasClass("right") ? "0" : "198px"`, а потом сделайте все остальное `$(this).toggleClass("right").animate({ right : rvalue}, 300);`